# how do I check curdepth in bash script?

Tags: bash, ibm-mq

I want to save the CURDEPTH as a variable in my bash script?  Is there a way to run this and save the curdepth ammount as a variable?

```
runmqsc QMGR
dis ql (##############) where(curdepth gt 1)
     3 : dis ql (##############) where(curdepth gt 1)
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(#############)          TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(71514)
end
```

Comment: Found it.echo "dis ql(#########) CURDEPTH" | runmqsc ##### | grep 'CURDEPTH(' | sed 's/.*CURDEPTH//' | tr -d '()'

Comment: How do you execute that as a command? That's not a bash script yet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
grep 'CURDEPTH(' | sed 's/.*CURDEPTH//' | tr -d '()'
```

You can do this if you have GNU grep

```
grep -oP '(?<=CURDEPTH\()\d+'
```

Otherwise, with one sed command

```
sed -n '/[[:blank:]]*CURDEPTH(\([[:digit:]]\+\))/s//\1/p'
```